# How to change path from field of IT to field of Space sciences?

Tags: career-path, changing-fields

I'm now at the final (4th) year of completing my bachelor's degree in IT. Four years back I haven't had any idea about what I'm choosing and in my country there were no space related degrees, therefore I enrolled in an IT degree. But I always had the passion for space and now I really need to chase that dream. I thought of applying for Masters' in space related programs but I'm afraid I'm lacking that university level engineering basis. And I don't know if I can afford to enroll another four year degree from scratch in a space related program, possibly in United States/Canada.

It's not that I don't love the field of IT, I'm having good grades and all but my passion lies in space industry. I had to make a wrong choice four years back and I want to make it right. The problem is affording to start from scratch. I'm 23 years old now.
So how can I still do this?
Thanks everyone for taking your time to read and reply :)

Comment: All rockets / shuttles etc have computers / IT... So apply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get out and work for a while.  Don't go to school forever.  Get some real world time.  You can make a change a few years from now if you still want to.  But you might even like work better.

Try for something in the aerospace industry, very broadly defined (aviation, airlines, defense, suppliers as ell as OEMs, etc.).  But I would consider normal IT jobs also.  You are an entry level person.  Any good experience will be good experience.

And you actually may prefer other industries (telecom, retail, software, heavy industry, natural resources etc.) more than aviation which can be rather bureaucratic because of the intense safety concerns and long product life cycles.  (But you don't know what you don't know.  Because you are 23 and haven't worked much.  Get some experiences.)

Note, that getting a "space degree" (whatever that is, I assume aeronautical/aerospace engineering) is no guarantee of a space industry posting.  Space remains a small industry.  I know a lot of aero grads who get normal engineering jobs.  And there are more MechEs designing planes and rockets than aero types (mechanical is the most general engineering degree, electrical second).  And planes and rockets and satellites are complex machines with different people developing and building different parts.

Answer (score 1):

Getting in any neighboring field is not always a matter of basic education. Space agencies indeed need engineers, but they for sure have a huge demand on IT specialists as any modern tech company. But you need to first search what kind of ITs are engaged in space industry (automation, simulation, modeling, integrated systems etc.). Then if you would like to do a master degree, choose one which will give you necessary skills. Furthermore, you can try searching internship/practice in a space-related company during your study. It is very probable they would hire you, if you did well.
Having an IT degree gives you pretty a lot of perspectives, but nowadays it is really about skills and what you learn by yourself. Google, visit career days, make personal contacts, learn and prosper.

Comment: Yeah I think you're correct. Thanks friend :)

Comment: @NoobGuy then if you think this answer is correct, you should accept this one... You can change ...